# Use of undefined constant db_selected - assumed 'db_selected

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//connecting to server
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$dbc){
    die('Not Connected : '.mysql_error());
    }
//connecting to database
$db_selected = mysql_selectdb("kalhan",$dbc);
if(!db_selected){
    die('Cannot Connect'.mysql_error());
    }
//testing database
$query = "UPDATE userinformation SET username = 'i am not working properly' where name = 'kalhan'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

The code shows the error mentioned above. I was just testing my database after the connection part of the coding...HELP

Answer (score 0):

You need a dollar-sign in front of db_selected

```
$db_selected = mysql_selectdb("kalhan",$dbc);

if(!db_selected){
//  ^-- No dollar sign
```

The error message is telling you that PHP assumed you meant to put `db_selected` in quotes so your condition becomes `if (!'db_selected')` which probably isn't what you want since that string evaluates to true every time.